# Correct way to pass values to Cloud function

Tags: php, json, parse-platform

I have tried various approaches but cannot seem to get this right.

When I pass data to the Cloud function I have trouble retrieving them in Cloud Code.

**Example:**

```
ParseCloud::run('addAlarm', ['subject' => $subject]);
```

Will pass the following request to the function in Cloud Code:

```
{"body":"{\"subject\":\"Re: Alarm\"}","params":{"subject":"Re: Alarm"},"installationId":"","user":null,"master":false}
```

I can read `request.body` to get:

```
{"subject":"Re: Alarm"}
```

But reading `request.body.subject` yields undefined

I was unable to find any examples where arguments is passed to the Cloud function in PHP, so am currently running on trial and error.

Comment: Your body is a String. You can either [`JSON.parse(request.body)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or use a function that sends an object instead

Comment: You can see that `request.body` is a string because the quotes are escaped (`\"`).

Comment: You are right. Tried encoding to JSON in PHP but resulted in 'invalid JSON' response from server. Will try `JSON.parse(request.body)`

Comment: @kingkero That was the key it seems! :) if you add it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"body":"{\"subject\":\"Re: Alarm\"}"
```

In your JSON the key `body` holds a **String** which looks like JSON. You can either use [`JSON.parse(request.body)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in your JavaScript or use a PHP method that sends the body as an object.